# Manually delete facebook cookie in FOSFacebookBundle

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I would like to manually delete the facebook cookie used by my application, in order to be able to regenerate a new access token when the user's one is not valid anymore.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
setcookie ("fbsr_YOUR_APP_ID", "", time() - 3600);
```

Edit:

There is an additional cookie "fbm_YOUR_APP_ID" which should be deleted too.

Comment: thanks, but it does not seem to solve my issue. I delete the cokies, call the `destroSession` method of the facebook php api, but I still have the same accessToken.

Comment: What happens after you delete the cookie? How do you get the same access token?

Comment: nothing happens. I use the fos_facebook.api service, can call destroySession, then I call getAccessToken, and it the same than before

Comment: The cookie is well deleted actually, thanks. But, I'm not able to generate a new token.

Comment: In order to get a new access token the user needs to authenticate again using the getLoginUrl method from the Facebook API.

Comment: But the user is still logged on Facebook, why would I need to redirect him to getLoginUrl in order to have a valid access token ?

Comment: You need to do so because you deleted the connection to your app by deleting the cookies. In order to get the connection back you need to get the cookies again.

Comment: If you are worried about the expiry of the access token, you can display the login url when it stops returning results.

Comment: I would like to use the FOSFacebookBundle entry point to connect the user again. Do you know how I can do that ? I try to invalidate my session when the token is expired, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Why do you need to invalidate the session? Why not get a new access token the same way you asked for it the first time? If the user accesses your app thru Facebook the token won't expire as long as the user is using the app.